# validating and save an uploaded ajax image in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, validation, file-upload, yii

I need to send an image to server via an ajax request and it gets through just fine
and in my controller I can just use `$_FILES["image"]` to do stuff to it.
But I need to validate the image before I save it.
And in the Yii this can be achieved by doing something like this

```
$file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
if($model->validated(array('image'))){
    $model->image->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/upload/user_thumb/' . $model->username.'.'.$model->photo->extensionName);
}
```

But the problem is I don't have a `$model`, all I have is `$_FILES["image"]`, now what should I put instead of the `$model`???
is there any other way where I can validate and save files without creating a model and just by Using `$_FILES["image"]`?
thanks for this awesome community... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists many ways how you can do upload. I want offer to you one of them.

1.You need to create model for your images.

```
class Image extends CActiveRecord {

    //method where need to specify validation rules
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['filename', 'length', 'max' => 40],
            //other rules
        ];
    }

    //this function allow to upload file
    public function doUpload($insName)
    {
        $file = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName($insName);
        if ($file) {
            $file->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/user_thumb/'.$this->filename.$file->getExtensionName());
        } else {
            $this->addError('Please, select at least one file'); // for example
        }
    }   
}
```

2.Now, need to create controller, where you will do all actions.

```
class ImageController extends CController {

    public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new Image();
        if (Yii::app()->request->getPost('upload')) {
            $model->filename = 'set filename';
            $insName = 'image'; //if you try to upload from $_FILES['image']
            if ($model->validate() && $model->doUpload($insName)) {
                //upload is successful
            } else {
                //do something with errors
                $errors = $model->getErrors();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: although this is not exactly what I was looking for, but you did show me to the right way and I found a way to Do it right, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a model might be overkill in some instances.

The $_FILE supervariable is part of the HTTP mechanism.

You can handle the copy by using the native PHP function move_uploaded_file()

```
   $fileName = "/uploads/".myimage.jpg";
   unlink($fileName);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $fileName);
```

However, you lose the niceties of using a library that provides additional functionality and checks (eg file type and file size limitations).

Comment: thanks a lot but as you said I needed the niceties of the Yii validation :)